# Proving Queue complexity by induction

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

I have two stacks that demonstrate a Queue, and the number of times we will be calling the Enqueue and Dequeue functions is n (#enqueue+#dequeue=n)

And I need to prove by induction that the complexity of the n function calling is Θ(n).

I know that I have to prove both Ω(n) and O(n). For Ω(n) I thought maybe I will get it if I'll call enqueue n times (each one is O(1) ) .

To be honest I'm new to this, and I don't have any idea how to start proving this by induction, anyone can give me a push please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm showing you the proof, But I'm not sure that it will be 100% correct.

## enqueue+dequeue=n;

T(enqueue)=O(1) as inserting it on the stack will only take 1 step.
T(dequeue)=O(n)

T(enqueue+dequeue)>=max(T(enqueue),T(dequeue))

T(n)>=max(O(1),O(n))

T(n)=O(n) , to prove

```
By Induction

    1. For n=1
     T(enqueue)=O(1) & T(dequeue)=O(1) 
     Therfore , T(1)=O(1).
    
    2. Let T(n) = O(n) is true
       Then , to prove T(n+1)=O(n)
       (By Rule : T(a+b)=T(a)+T(b))
       So, 
       T(n+1)=T(n)+T(1)
             =O(n)+O(1) (from above explanation)
             =max(O(n)+O(1))
             =O(n)
     Hence Proved , T(n+1)=O(n) or T(n)=O(n)
```

Comment: Many Thanks!  it seems to be logical
Just one more question, how is T(dequeue)=O(1)  when n=1? (in case you need just to pop a value from the other stack?)

Comment: @Davekur : Yes , for n=1 , you just have to pop it from stack.